# Python: creating exe installer of python project

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller

I want to create an installer for my python project, which runs on any Windows PC without directly installing python on that PC.

Basically what I need is that my python project installs and runs on PC as any other software.

I've already tried `pyinstaller` but it converts only a single file. I don't know if it does work for a whole project.

Comment: The exe file it creates just needs to have access to all the dependencies. You can accomplish this by putting them all into a folder and sending the folder zipped to wherever it needs to go.

Comment: @Bill I've the exe and its dependencies in a folder already, Now I need to create a installer which takes all the files and install it to the computer. Just one single file which installs the whole package

Comment: This video might help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UZX5kH72Yx4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please install AUTO-PY-TO-EXE

Auto-py-to-exe have gui to convert exe it has a option for one directory and one file

```
pip install auto-py-to-exe
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The single file `pyinstaller` outputs contains the whole project you told it to generate for you.

You can just distribute that file, and anyone can download it and run with double-click.

To create an installer, you can use something like NSIS installer.

Comment: I realy appreciate the help, I just need the NSIS installer rest was already done.